# texshop knitr -> XeLaTeX engine

Tags: xetex, mac, texshop, knitr

In TeXShop, my current knitr engine is

```
#!/bin/bash
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/texbin:/usr/local/bin
Rscript -e "library(knitr); knit('$1')"
latexmk -pdf "${1%.*}"
```

My current XeLaTeX engine is

```
#!/bin/tcsh

set path= ($path /Library/TeX/texbin /usr/texbin /usr/local/bin)
xelatex  -file-line-error -synctex=1 "$1"
```

1. How do I replace latexmk with an equivalent xelatex command in the knitr engine?
2. The current default shell in MacOS is zsh. Could the response  to 1 include a modification for zsh.

Comment: Try `latexmk -xelatex "${1%.*}"`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you might want to keep latexmk, to make sure the document is fully compiled. If you create a `latexmkrc` file in your working directory containing

```
$pdf_mode = 1;
$pdflatex = 'xelatex -file-line-error -synctex=1 %O %S';
```

then latexmk will use the invocation there, and you can even remove "-pdf" from the call.

(%O stands for latexmk options, e.g. if you set $recorder = 1, then -recorder will be added here; %S stands for the file name.)

You could also set this using the -pdflatex switch to latexmk.